# Accessing ParentViewController properties

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad application with a UISplitView implemented. Within the UISplitView, I have some data being stored. A simple ID. I need to obtain this ID in the child view controllers of this UISplitView and I cannot figure out how to do it.

Here is what I have in my splitView.h file

```
 @interface SplitView : UISplitViewController{
     int reportId;
 }

 @property(nonatomic, assign) int reportId;
```

This is how I was attempting to obtain the data from the detail view. I have my main view inside a navigation view controller first, then inside the splitview, so I am calling like:

```
 SplitView *mainVC = (SplitView *)[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController];
 NSLog(@"Getting report ID: %i", [mainVC reportId]);
```

** This code doesn't work. It makes sense to me... But obviously I am doing something wrong. Any help is apprecaited.

Comment: Shouldn't you be casting to ChemicalReportSplitView not to SplitView? Not sure if you did that on purpose or not..

Comment: I am, but to make the code easier to read I changed it, and forgot to change the one. Sorry, any recommendations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I passing data from parent view controller to child view controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238565/how-can-i-passing-data-from-parent-view-controller-to-child-view-controller)