# How can I passing data from parent view controller to child view controller?

Tags: ios, delegates

How can I passing data from parent view controller to child view controller?

I tried doing this with delegates. but I don't think it's an option?

Comment: Why use delegates for this? Simply have the parent view controller set a property (or 2 or 3) as needed when the parent view controller creates the child view controller. It no different than creating and setting up any other object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Option 1

If you're passing from a parent to a child view controller, then just set the property of your childViewController from the parent.

```
customChildViewController.someRandomProperty = @"some random value";
[self presentViewController:customChildViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

#### Option 2

Or, you can set up a delegate

Step 1: set up protocol above interface in ChildViewController.h file

```
@protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate

- (NSDictionary *) giveMeData;

@end

@interface  .....
```

Step 2: create delegate property in ChildViewController.h interface

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<ChildViewControllerDelegate>delegate
```

Step 3: declare delegate protocol in ParentViewController.h

```
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController <ChildViewControllerDelegate>
```

Step 4: in ParentViewController.m add this method:

```
- (NSDictionary *) giveMeData {
    NSMutableDictionary * dataToReturn = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    dataToReturn[@"some"] = @"random";
    dataToReturn[@"data"] = @"here";
    return dataToReturn;
}
```

Step 5: before launching childViewController declare delegate property.

```
childViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:childViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Step 6: in child view controller whenever you want data add this

```
NSMutableDictionary * dataFromParent = [self.delegate giveMeData];
```

The parentVC will run 'giveMeData' and return a NSMutableDictionary (adjust for whatever data you want)

Answer (score 2):

You can access your child view controllers by:

```
NSArray *children = self.childViewControllers;
```

Comment: That is not what was asked.