# Pass data from View Controller to Child Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parent-child

I have three View Controllers (VC1, Parent View Controller and Child View Controller). How do I pass data from the VC1 to the child View controller when the ParentVC is loaded? Normally I would be able to use this in the First View Controller

```
var text = "Hello"
var sVC = SecondViewController()
sVC.string = text
```

and it would pass `Hello` to the variable `string` in the second view controller. and then do the same thing to pass data from the Second View Controller to the third one. But unfortunately, this logic is not working. I've tried to pass the the data from VC1 to the ParentVC then to the ChildVC. I've also tried to pass the data from VC1 directly to the ChildVC but that does not seem to work either.

Here is what I have

```
import UIKit
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

var a = "Test"

override func viewDidLoad() {
   var pVC = ParentViewController()
   pVC.a = a
  }
}
```

I'm able to pass data to the Parent View Controller and it prints `Test` but it does not for the Child View Controller

```
import UIKit

class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

var pageMenu: CAPSPageMenu?
var a = ""

 func test() {

  var cvC = ChildViewController(frame: self.view.frame)
   cvC.a = a
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
   println(a)

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // MARK: - Scroll menu setup

    // Initialize view controllers to display and place in array
    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

    var controller1 : ChildViewController = ChildViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    controller1.title = "View Controller"
    controllerArray.append(controller1)

    // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 65, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

    }
}
```

And in the Child View Controller I have:

```
import UIKit

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

var a = ""

convenience init(frame:CGRect){
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.view.frame = frame

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
   var pVC = ParentViewController()
   pVC.test()
   println(a)
}
```

Comment: What is `cvC` in your code?

Comment: It's supposed to be a variable. I'll edit it.

Comment: You are creating new controllers every time. `ChildViewController` creates a new `ParentViewController` when the view it's loaded and `ParentViewController` creates new `ChildViewController`s in `test` method and `viewDidAppear` again, but you only pass the `a` property in the `test` method, that does nothing with the child controller.

Comment: How do I pass it to the `ChildViewController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When loading the `ParentViewController` from your `ViewController`, there are no views loaded into memory. It's just an instance of your `ParentViewController` class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   var pVC = ParentViewController()
   pVC.a = a
}
```

And i guess you are loading or presenting this controller somewhere else in your code. If so, it makes sense that you're successfully printing the variable being set.

> println(a) -> "Test"

However, when you are instantiating your `ChildViewController`, you are providing a frame for its `convenience init` and you are actually initiating the view hierarchy, which in turn fires the `viewDidLoad` event. This is executed before the `a` variable is being set from `ParentViewController -> ViewDidLoad`. And your result from printing the `a` variable is actually an empty string.

One option is to put your logic within their own functions that you explicitly call. Optionally with your data as parameters or you set the variables before calling the function(s).

You should check out some of these to get a better understanding of how things work and paths you can follow to accomplish what you want.

[Instantiate and Present a viewController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift)

[UIViewController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/)

[How can I passing data from parent view controller to child view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238565/how-can-i-passing-data-from-parent-view-controller-to-child-view-controller)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried putting it into a function that is explicitly called from the child VC but this didn't work. I updated the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: That wasn't exactly what i had in mind. Please let us know if you're intending to use storyboard when setting up these views or are they programmatically made ?