# How to pass data from a tableview to a different uiviewcontroller

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I am writing an application that is going to contain a tableview that contains a list of days. When a day is clicked, I would like to display a page that contains information with text and a button that is unique to each day.

I was planning on creating a different view controller that would be specific to each day. However, I do not know how to pass the data from the tableview for each day to the specific view controller of the specific day selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data from View Controller to Child Controller in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284217/pass-data-from-view-controller-to-child-controller-in-swift)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UITableView` delegate method for **click event** in your tableview 
You need to implement `UITableViewDelegate`. For passing data to specific view controller you may want to use `prepareForSegue` function

```
var day = [1,2,3,4,5]
var selected_day : Int = 0
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       self.day.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourcellidentifier") as! yourtableViewCell
        cell.labelday.text = self.day[indexPath.row]// just sample
        return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //this method will be called when you click 1 of the row from tableview
        self.selected_day = self.day[indexPath.row]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToYourSpecificViewController", sender: self) // you have to link with your table view controller and your specific view controller with an identifier.  
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
         if segue.destinationViewController is YourSpecificViewController{
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! YourSpecificViewController
            // In YourSpecificViewController, you also need to declare a variable name called selected_day to catch 
            vc.selected_day = self.selected_day
         }
    }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you so much! Do I have to do anything in my storyboard as well, or just this code?

Comment: you need to link this view controller and YourSpecifiViewController and set segue id, use it in here `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToYourSpecificViewController", sender: self)`

Answer (score 0):

In the view controller with the table, implement the `prepareforsegue()` method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    let row = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

    if segue.identifier == "Sunday" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SundayViewController
        vc.myInt = dataModel[row!].theInt  // This changes depending on how your data is set up and whether you're grabbing the info from a text field, or what have you
    }

    else if segue.identifier == "Monday" {   
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MondayViewController
        vc.myInt = dataModel[row!].theInt
        vc.someString = dataModel[row!].theString
    }
}
```

The days' view controllers would look like:

```
class SundayViewController: UIViewController {

    var myInt: Int?
    // etc
}

class MondayViewController: UIViewController {

    var myInt: Int?
    var someString: String?
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your tableviewcontroller implement this code

```
class TableviewController: UITableViewController {

    var array : [DayObject]? = [DayObject(day: "Sunday", daytext: "SundayText"),DayObject(day: "Monday", daytext: "MondayText"),DayObject(day: "tuesday", daytext: "TuesdayText"),DayObject(day: "Wednesday", daytext: "WednesdayText")]
    var object: DayObject?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}

extension TableviewController {


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (array!.count)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = array![indexPath.row].day
        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        object =  array![indexPath.row]
        performSegueWithIdentifier("NVC", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "NVC" {
            let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2
            dvc!.object = object
        }
    }

}
```

and make a datamodel as below:

```
import UIKit
class DayObject: NSObject {

    var day: String!
    var daytext: String!


    init(day: String, daytext: String) {
        self.day = day
        self.daytext =  daytext
    }
}
```

and in your view controller you can collect the object

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    var object: DayObject!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(object.daytext)
    }
}
```

By datamodel approach you dont have to make different view controllers for each day

happycoding :-)